# How to Use BUSD coin when we buy the NFT In React.js with Binance Block chain

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, binance-smart-chain

Hi we want to create a NFT market place.my project almost done but currently we are using BNB for the purchase NFT and also Gas fee. but I want to change Currency Type BUSD

```
const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
/* next, create the item */
const contract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, signer);
const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.1", "ether");
// console.log(provider);
const transaction = await contract.mint(url);

const tx = await transaction.wait();
// console.log(tx);
const _event = tx.events[0];
const value = _event?.args[2];
const tokenId = value.toNumber();
// console.log(_event);



const tokenURI = await contract.tokenURI(tokenId)
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out ?